# Getting error invalid json token in laravel package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, google-api-client

Currently implement a google drive API.Getting error **invalid json token** in laravel package.I want to upload file in after create a folder in google drive. Created app is work but after redirection nothing happen. If anyone can help.

**Tutorial Link ** : https://www.sitepoint.com/is-laravel-good-enough-to-power-a-custom-google-drive-ui/

Might be package is deprecated

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Googl;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        return view('login');
    }


    public function login(Googl $googl, Request $request)
    {
        $client = $googl->client();

        if ($request->has('code')) {            
            $client->authenticate($request->input('code'));
            $token = $client->getAccessToken();

            $plus = new \Google_Service_Plus($client);

            $google_user = $plus->people->get('me');
            $id = $google_user['id'];

            $email = $google_user['emails'][0]['value'];
            $first_name = $google_user['name']['givenName'];
            $last_name = $google_user['name']['familyName'];

            session([
                'user' => [
                    'email' => $email,
                    'first_name' => $first_name,
                    'last_name' => $last_name,
                    'token' => $token
                ]
            ]);


            return redirect('/dashboard')->with('message', ['type' => 'success', 'text' => 'You are now logged in.']);

        } else {
            $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
            return redirect($auth_url);
        }
   }
}
```

Stack Trace : 
[image]

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace?

Comment: yes give me moment.

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: @IlGala is it something you can help with? do you need anything  else?

Comment: Dude please check whether the JSON token that your passing is valid or not. Check the token from where you got it

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I think the problem comes out when you call the `$googl->client()` method. Since from the StackTrace comes out that a null token is received when calling [`setAccessToken()` method](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php#L418)... I think you should check the environment variables or the google developers console...

Comment: Yes I have check I get access token

Comment: This line have array  $token = $client->getAccessToken();

Comment: The error is coming from AdminController, what's happening in its constructor ?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter You are right. Thanks for pointing let me check.

Comment: Its redirect but still no file upload using above method.

Comment: Could it be your session['user'][...] array? I'm sure all is correct. It seems odd that a package will look into ['user']['token'] instead of ['_token'] or ['token']. I have no experience with google drive and its package. It's just a gut feeling.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I will redirect to json page but getting error of json sometime error regarding login.

Comment: @VasimVanzara yes it is possible that the tutorial is outdated (2 years old). Unfortunately not enough time here to verify that. But to dig into the problem I would check in Client.php (especially before line #420)  what response is coming to the client, cause obviously in this case, $token matches null. One more thing - maybe silly question. Since you are not receiving token, are you 100% sure that your client is properly set up on google and you have all respective keys properly set/copied to your app config files?

Comment: if you think the document is out dated, so you can use the older version of google-api-client like v2.1.3 which is released 2 years ago.

Comment: what should I do, brother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment, but it seems I can't yet...

From your screenshot I can see that the problem is in *AdminController.php* on **line 16**. Can you please share this code instead. The `setAccessToken()` is receiving the `null` object, so the problem lies there.

Answer (score 0):

**First Check:**

From the tutorial you linked to (and without seeing it I am assuming this is what you have) it looks like the AdminController constructor is trying to retrieve the token from the user.token session variable. It is worth checking that this actually contains a token before using it.

**Something to try:**

Looking back at my implementation of this from a few months ago it looks like I struggled retrieving the correct token string from the Google Client. Instead of:

```
if ($request->has('code')) {            
    ...
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    ...
```

Try something like:

```
if ($request->has('code')) {   
    $fullToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
    $client->setAccessToken($fullToken);
```